# Unable to understand the drawable structure inside res folder

Tags: android, drawable

I am newbie as far as android application development is considered.

I am little bit confused about drawable folders.

In the tutorials available on the android developer site they have mentioned about the drawable folder. But when I create android 2.3.3 application I see three folders `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-ldpi`.

I know that this for screen resolutions. If I have an image as a resource I have to create equivalent three images with different sizes and put these images into these three folders.

But for example, I am working on a localization (German) with images. Should I create folder `drawable-hdpi-de-rDE` similarly `drawable-mdpi-de-rDE` and `drawable-ldpi-de-rDE` or should `drawable-de-rDE` be sufficient?

If `drawable-de-rDE` is sufficient what will happen if it is run in mdpi or ldpi?

Please clear my doubts regarding this.

Thanks

Pankaj

Answer (score 4):

> Should i create folder
> drawable-hdpi-de-rDE similarly
> drawable-mdpi-de-rDE &
> drawable-ldpi-de-rDE

If you want to make your pictures (at the right sizes) yourself, yes, you'll have to create directories that are specific to both the culture and pixel density. However, the culture should come before the dpi, or the project will not compile. For example, the following would compile correctly:

drawable-de-rDE-hdpi 
drawable-de-rDE-mdpi 
drawable-de-rDE-ldpi

> should drawable-de-rDE will be
> sufficient?

If you don't feel the need to draw your pictures at the right scale yourself, that should work : android will scale the images to the right size, as needed.

But note that you might get better graphics doing that scaling yourself -- and, instead of just scale up/down, you could re-think your images a little bit, so they fit better in different sizes.

Comment: Thanks pascal for replying. Creating folders like drawable-hdpi-de-rDE results in an error:[2011-04-04 14:35:14 - HelloL10N] invalid resource directory name: C:\Documents and Settings\abc\workspace\HelloL10N\res/drawable-hdpi-de-rDE

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html