# How to keep images inside a second level folder and access in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I need to keep images inside a second level folder in `res` and access through java and xml. But when I import the image folder to `res` or outside it shows errors.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't** in `/res` directory. Android resources doesn't support like second level directory hierarchy. because of generation of id in R.java file.

The only way is either put those images in `/asset` so its allowed second level directory hierarchy.

Or just rename your images like with folder name prefix and put as it is in res directory.

Answer (score 0):

Images should be kept inside a folder named drawable in res folder. U can read the following link:

---

### [Unable to understand the drawable structure inside res folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537208/unable-to-understand-the-drawable-structure-inside-res-folder)